# Bluetooth mouse constantly fails to reconnect after sleep, Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: suspend, bluetooth, mouse, 20.10

Bluetooth Mouth work fine until sleep. After resuming from sleep however, the mouse will try to reconnect then, failing that, turns itself off.

This issue arose only after updating to 20.10 (from 20.04). In fact, in the past decade, every time when I upgrade Ubuntu to something, Bluetooth stops working.

`lsusb` says I have

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
```

The mount is Logitech MX Master 2S.

3 workaround works. This post asks for a method to return it to the Ubuntu 20.04 level of experience (that the mouse connects by clicking).

- Reboot Ubuntu
- Plugin another mouse and use it to access the Bluetooth configuration, choose the mount "MX Master 2S" and flip "Connection" Switch on.
- Run this command (with the ID of my mouse)

```
$ echo connect DA:8E:70:A2:34:F1 | bluetoothctl
```